# Errors when trying to quantize a tflite-model-maker model -- Invalid begin and size.Node number XX (SLICE) failed to invoke

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, quantization

My specific question is (details below):

Why does this code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tflite_model_maker import audio_classifier

spec = audio_classifier.BrowserFftSpec()

rep_dir = './dataset-rep' # Contains a reduced set of ~100 audio samples
rep_data = audio_classifier.DataLoader.from_folder(
      spec, rep_dir, cache=False)

def representative_dataset():
      representative_dataset = rep_data.gen_dataset()
      for audio, label in representative_dataset:
            yield [audio]


converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("/path/to/saved_model")
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset

converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]

converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8

tflite_model = converter.convert()


with open ('./models/quantModel.tflite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)
```

produce the error: `RuntimeError: Invalid begin and size.Node number 13 (SLICE) failed to invoke.` (originates from the `converter.convert()` line). And how can I fix it?

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./model_conversion.py", line 54, in <module>
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 933, in wrapper
    return self._convert_and_export_metrics(convert_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 911, in _convert_and_export_metrics
    result = convert_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 1216, in convert
    return self._convert_from_saved_model(graph_def)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 1100, in _convert_from_saved_model
    return self._optimize_tflite_model(
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert_phase.py", line 215, in wrapper
    raise error from None  # Re-throws the exception.
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert_phase.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 871, in _optimize_tflite_model
    model = self._quantize(model, q_in_type, q_out_type, q_activations_type,
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 613, in _quantize
    calibrated = calibrate_quantize.calibrate(
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert_phase.py", line 215, in wrapper
    raise error from None  # Re-throws the exception.
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert_phase.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/optimize/calibrator.py", line 226, in calibrate
    self._feed_tensors(dataset_gen, resize_input=True)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/optimize/calibrator.py", line 138, in _feed_tensors
    self._calibrator.FeedTensor(input_array)
RuntimeError: Invalid begin and size.Node number 13 (SLICE) failed to invoke.
```

The model was trained according the example "[Retrain a speech recognition model with TensorFlow Lite Model Maker](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/modify/model_maker/speech_recognition)" and I can run the test inference on it using the example code provided. Now I'd like to put it on a microcontroller that only supports `int8` inputs (an ESP32) so I need to quantize my model. When I try to convert, this is what I get. Note that if I try to convert it in the same file as the training is completed, using

```
... train model, etc...
quantization_config = QuantizationConfig.for_int8(rep_data) # takes the raw data instead of representative_dataset()
model.export(SAVE_PATH, tflite_filename=QUANT_FILENAME, quantization_config = quantization_config)
```

I get the same error (except it is `...node.Number 11...`).

Any suggestions would be appreciated as I'm somewhat out of my depth with TensorFlow. I've tried piecemeal upgrading packages to see if this is a bug that is resolved by updating, but that doesn't appear(?) to be the case (see below). I'm running in WSL inside a conda environment, but I don't think that should make a difference.

It is possible that I'm in a weird dependency problem as `tflite-model-maker` (and some of its dependencies, particularly `scann`) seems to want a lower version of `tensorflow` than what is current. For reference, here are the versions that I'm working with (installed via `pip install tflite-model-maker`):

```
python 3.9.16

Package                       Version
----------------------------- --------
absl-py                       1.4.0
appdirs                       1.4.4
array-record                  0.2.0
astunparse                    1.6.3
attrs                         23.1.0
audioread                     3.0.0
cachetools                    5.3.0
certifi                       2023.5.7
cffi                          1.15.1
charset-normalizer            3.1.0
click                         8.1.3
cycler                        0.11.0
Cython                        0.29.34
dataclasses                   0.6
decorator                     5.1.1
dm-tree                       0.1.8
etils                         1.3.0
fire                          0.5.0
flatbuffers                   23.5.9
gast                          0.4.0
gin-config                    0.5.0
google-api-core               2.11.0
google-api-python-client      2.86.0
google-auth                   2.18.0
google-auth-httplib2          0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib          0.4.6
google-cloud-bigquery         3.10.0
google-cloud-core             2.3.2
google-crc32c                 1.5.0
google-pasta                  0.2.0
google-resumable-media        2.5.0
googleapis-common-protos      1.59.0
grpcio                        1.54.2
grpcio-status                 1.48.2
h5py                          3.8.0
httplib2                      0.22.0
idna                          3.4
importlib-metadata            6.6.0
importlib-resources           5.12.0
jax                           0.4.10
joblib                        1.2.0
kaggle                        1.5.13
keras                         2.11.0
Keras-Preprocessing           1.1.2
kiwisolver                    1.4.4
lazy_loader                   0.2
libclang                      16.0.0
librosa                       0.8.1
llvmlite                      0.36.0
lxml                          4.9.2
Markdown                      3.4.3
MarkupSafe                    2.1.2
matplotlib                    3.4.3
ml-dtypes                     0.1.0
msgpack                       1.0.5
neural-structured-learning    1.4.0
numba                         0.53.0
numpy                         1.23.5
oauthlib                      3.2.2
opencv-python-headless        4.7.0.72
opt-einsum                    3.3.0
packaging                     20.9
pandas                        2.0.1
Pillow                        9.5.0
pip                           23.1.2
platformdirs                  3.5.1
pooch                         1.6.0
promise                       2.3
proto-plus                    1.22.2
protobuf                      3.19.6
psutil                        5.9.5
py-cpuinfo                    9.0.0
pyasn1                        0.5.0
pyasn1-modules                0.3.0
pybind11                      2.10.4
pycparser                     2.21
pyparsing                     3.0.9
python-dateutil               2.8.2
python-slugify                8.0.1
pytz                          2023.3
PyYAML                        6.0
requests                      2.30.0
requests-oauthlib             1.3.1
resampy                       0.4.2
rsa                           4.9
scann                         1.2.9
scikit-learn                  1.2.2
scipy                         1.10.1
seaborn                       0.12.2
sentencepiece                 0.1.99
setuptools                    67.7.2
six                           1.16.0
sounddevice                   0.4.6
soundfile                     0.12.1
soxr                          0.3.5
tensorboard                   2.11.2
tensorboard-data-server       0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit        1.8.1
tensorflow                    2.11.1
tensorflow-addons             0.20.0
tensorflow-datasets           4.9.0
tensorflow-estimator          2.11.0
tensorflow-hub                0.12.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.32.0
tensorflow-metadata           1.13.0
tensorflow-model-optimization 0.7.4
tensorflowjs                  3.18.0
termcolor                     2.3.0
text-unidecode                1.3
tf-models-official            2.3.0
tf-slim                       1.1.0
tflite-model-maker            0.4.2
tflite-support                0.4.3
threadpoolctl                 3.1.0
toml                          0.10.2
tqdm                          4.65.0
typeguard                     2.13.3
typing_extensions             4.5.0
tzdata                        2023.3
uritemplate                   4.1.1
urllib3                       1.25.11
Werkzeug                      2.3.4
wheel                         0.40.0
wrapt                         1.14.1
zipp                          3.15.0
```

I haven't seen other errors of this type while looking around online, but it is entirely possible I've just missed them or it's something obvious that I'm doing wrong.

**Edit:**
Model is created using:

```
import os
import glob
import random
import shutil

import librosa
import soundfile as sf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

import tensorflow as tf
import tflite_model_maker as mm
from tflite_model_maker import audio_classifier
from tflite_model_maker.config import ExportFormat
from tflite_model_maker.config import QuantizationConfig

print(f"TensorFlow Version: {tf.__version__}")
print(f"Model Maker Version: {mm.__version__}")

use_custom_dataset = False



tf.keras.utils.get_file('speech_commands_v0.01.tar.gz',
                        'http://download.tensorflow.org/data/speech_commands_v0.01.tar.gz',
                        cache_dir='./',
                        cache_subdir='dataset-speech',
                        extract=True)

tf.keras.utils.get_file('background_audio.zip',
                        'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/tflite/sound_classification/background_audio.zip',
                        cache_dir='./',
                        cache_subdir='dataset-background',
                        extract=True)


# Create a list of all the background wav files
files = glob.glob(os.path.join('./dataset-speech/_background_noise_', '*.wav'))
files = files + glob.glob(os.path.join('./dataset-background', '*.wav'))

background_dir = './background'
#os.makedirs(background_dir, exist_ok=True)

# Loop through all files and split each into several one-second wav files
for file in files:
  filename = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(file))
  print('Splitting', filename)
  name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
  rate = librosa.get_samplerate(file)
  length = round(librosa.get_duration(filename=file))
  for i in range(length - 1):
    start = i * rate
    stop = (i * rate) + rate
    data, _ = sf.read(file, start=start, stop=stop)
    sf.write(os.path.join(background_dir, name + str(i) + '.wav'), data, rate)

if not use_custom_dataset:
  commands = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven",
              "eight", "nine", "zero", "marvin", "stop"]
  dataset_dir = './dataset-speech'
  test_dir = './dataset-test'

  # Move the processed background samples
  #shutil.move(background_dir, os.path.join(dataset_dir, 'background'))   

  # Delete all directories that are not in our commands list
  dirs = glob.glob(os.path.join(dataset_dir, '*/'))
  for dir in dirs:
    name = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(dir))
    if name not in commands:
      shutil.rmtree(dir)

  # Count is per class
  sample_count = 150
  test_data_ratio = 0.2
  test_count = round(sample_count * test_data_ratio)

  # Loop through child directories (each class of wav files)
  dirs = glob.glob(os.path.join(dataset_dir, '*/'))
  for dir in dirs:
    files = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir, '*.wav'))
    random.seed(42)
    random.shuffle(files)
    # Move test samples:
    for file in files[sample_count:sample_count + test_count]:
      class_dir = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(dir))
      os.makedirs(os.path.join(test_dir, class_dir), exist_ok=True)
      os.rename(file, os.path.join(test_dir, class_dir, os.path.basename(file)))
    # Delete remaining samples
    for file in files[sample_count + test_count:]:
      os.remove(file)

spec = audio_classifier.BrowserFftSpec()

if not use_custom_dataset:
  train_data_ratio = 0.8
  train_data = audio_classifier.DataLoader.from_folder(
      spec, dataset_dir, cache=True)
  train_data, validation_data = train_data.split(train_data_ratio)
  test_data = audio_classifier.DataLoader.from_folder(
      spec, test_dir, cache=True)
  

# If your dataset has fewer than 100 samples per class,
# you might want to try a smaller batch size
batch_size = 25
epochs = 25
model = audio_classifier.create(train_data, spec, validation_data, batch_size, epochs)

model.evaluate(test_data)

def show_confusion_matrix(confusion, test_labels):
  """Compute confusion matrix and normalize."""
  confusion_normalized = confusion.astype("float") / confusion.sum(axis=1)
  sns.set(rc = {'figure.figsize':(6,6)})
  sns.heatmap(
      confusion_normalized, xticklabels=test_labels, yticklabels=test_labels,
      cmap='Blues', annot=True, fmt='.2f', square=True, cbar=False)
  plt.title("Confusion matrix")
  plt.ylabel("True label")
  plt.xlabel("Predicted label")

confusion_matrix = model.confusion_matrix(test_data)
show_confusion_matrix(confusion_matrix.numpy(), test_data.index_to_label)

TFLITE_FILENAME = 'browserfft-speech.tflite'
QUANT_FILENAME = 'browserfft-int8.tflite'
SAVE_PATH = './models'

print(f'Exporing the model to {SAVE_PATH}')
model.export(SAVE_PATH, tflite_filename=TFLITE_FILENAME)
model.export(SAVE_PATH, export_format=[mm.ExportFormat.SAVED_MODEL, mm.ExportFormat.LABEL])

rep_dir = './dataset-rep'
rep_data = audio_classifier.DataLoader.from_folder(
      spec, rep_dir, cache=True)

def representative_dataset():
  representative_dataset = rep_data.gen_dataset()
  for audio, label in representative_dataset:
            yield [audio]

quantization_config = QuantizationConfig.for_int8(rep_data)
model.export(SAVE_PATH, tflite_filename=QUANT_FILENAME, quantization_config = quantization_config)
```

Comment: Can I see how you create the model?

Comment: I've added the code used to create the model -- it's almost verbatim copied from the TF example, but I did change the keywords.